# Validation for Negative numbers

Tags: java, validation

```
System.out.print("Price of the book? ");
        while (!keyboard.hasNextDouble() || priceOfBook <=0)
        {
        System.err.print("Invalid input - Price of " + bookTitle + "? ");
        keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        priceOfBook = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

I am trying to validate the above code basically so that user can't enter negative numbers or letters or empty doubles but it's not working and I can't see where I'm going wrong. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What happens exactly?

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in order. the priceOfBook is not set before you set it. You can step through your code in your debugger to get a better idea of what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So how i understand you need to real line until the user didint enter negative or letter.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double x = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter price");

    while (true) {
        if (!sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println("Sorry price cant be negative or be letter");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Enter price");
        x = sc.nextDouble();
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You put

```
    priceOfBook = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

outside of your while loop :) Try like this:

```
while (priceOfBook <= 0)
{
  System.err.print("Invalid input - Price of " + bookTitle + "? ");
  priceOfBook = keyboard.nextDouble();
}
```

So that it will keep asking the user if he enters a number < 0.

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign the user's input to `priceOfBook` until *after* the `while` loop. So, when your loop checks if `priceOfBook` is negative, it doesn't check the user's input, but the previously stored value (if there is one). This allows the user's input (even if it's negative) to pass the `while` loop, and then get saved as `priceOfBook`.

Try instead:

```
while (!keyboard.hasNextDouble() || priceOfBook = keyboard.nextDouble() <=0) {
    System.err.print("Invalid input - Price of " + bookTitle + "? ");
    keyboard.nextLine();
}
```